# Filtering out bots and spiders for ad system. Blocking gone too far

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, bots

We have an in house ad system, and are constantly fighting bots and spiders. Obviously we want to get to as close to 100% valid impressions as possible and I have a particular ad zone that I experiment with.

This ad zone appears on only 1 page of the site, so I compare our Google Analytics page views for that page to the impression count for that ad zone and try to get them as close as possible.

Basic protections include, a known bot/spider list, serving the ads with javascript, and a honeypot to automatically collect new scrapers/bots.

This puts ad delivery at 130-150% of page views. Meaning, bots are triggering impressions, but not page views.

So then I started only loading the ads on mouse movement and delivery dropped to 40-60% of page views.

Now this is desktop only, no mobile.

What am I not thinking of that fulfillment is now so low? There aren't that many people with JS turned off, or browsing without mice.

I actually assumed that I would barely interrupt impressions, thinking that most bots would simulate mouse movement, not that I would drop them so low.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

**EDIT WITH JS SNIPPET**

```
adShow = 0;
document.onmousemove = function(){
    if (adShow == 0) {
            var leaderboard = CODE_FOR_AD;
            var adLeaderboard = document.querySelector('.adspace-leaderboard#adspace');
            adLeaderboard.innerHTML = leaderboard;
            adShow = 1;             
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the javascript snippet by which you detect the mouse movement and trigger the ad-load?
Maybe there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Posted the JS snippet.

Comment: Where did you put this JavaScript in your page? In the head?

Answer (score 0):

As you commented to this answer (as I expected) you placed the JS snippet right after the opening `body`-tag, so before the actual HTML element (same would happen if you placed this snippet in the `head` section of the page).
It is quite likely that someone moves the mouse during the loading of the page, and so the mousemove event might be executed before the HTML element is there and thus the ad-space will never be actually loaded.

You could fix that easily by either placing the snippet right before the `</body>` closing tag, or by wrapping the code in an `onDomReady` or `onLoad` event. The last two will make the code execute respectively after all DOM has been loaded or even after all assets (images, etc.) have been loaded. In your case `onDomReady` would be enough.

Like this:

```
document.onDomReady = function(){
    adShow = 0;
    document.onmousemove = function(){
        if (adShow == 0) {
                var leaderboard = CODE_FOR_AD;
                var adLeaderboard = document.querySelector('.adspace-leaderboard#adspace');
                adLeaderboard.innerHTML = leaderboard;
                adShow = 1;             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After the ".adspace-leaderboard#adspace" elements?

Comment: No. Right under the opening body tag.

Comment: Ok, so that's what I think the problem is. So I think you should try the above, or place the JS right under body-closing tag.

Comment: So did my answer fix your problem? If so, could you tag my answer as "the answer"?

Comment: It did not have an effect. I am guessing that in the time it takes to acknowledge the mouse move and load the ad people are able to click and leave the page before the ad is loaded.

Comment: But one cannot click without a mouse move. So I think you should add something like a Google Analytics event in the mousemove callback. Then if that statistic is the same as the other statistic, you know that the problem is in the callback. Otherwise, if the number of the GA event is way higher, the problem is in the loading of the ad.